# Adjoint functors for Lie Algebras

Tags: lie-algebras, adjoint-functors, functors

Let's restrict to finite dimensional case.

Functor $(-)^{\mathrm{ab}}: \mathrm{LieAlg} \to \mathrm{AbLieAlg}$ is left adjoint of the inclusion functor $i: \mathrm{AbLieAlg} \to \mathrm{LieAlg}$. Consider the same construction for inclusion of other categories of: Nilpotent Lie Algebras, Solvable Lie Algebras, Simple Lie Algebras into the category of finite dimensional Lie algebras.

The question is: What do we get as left adjoint in these cases?

I'm almost sure that in first two cases we will get factorization by limit of lower (resp. upper) central series. But for Simple Algebras maybe there is no adjoint functor.

Comment: Are you sure that there are left adjoints in the case of nilpotent or solvable? I'd expect adjoints for $n$-step nilpotent or $n$-step solvable, for any fixed $n$, but I have doubts about the situation with no bound on $n$.